# Brake pedal stuck, no crank, no horn after sleeping in car

Tags: honda, brakes, ignition, abs

Not sure what might've happened, but I slept in my car for a little bit and mistakenly slept pressing down the brake pedal.

When I woke up, I tried to turn on the car and I wouldn't get any crank whatsoever and the ABS and Brake System lights would come on.

I tried manually pulling the break pedal up, but I didn't push it too much since I didn't want to damage some other mechanical system.

I then left the car, and locked my doors, to my surprise the car's horn didn't sound either, even though all the doors were closed properly *(I double checked)*

I have a Honda Accord Sport 2017 that I got brand new from the dealership, and this is the first mechanical issue I've had with it so far so I don't think it's a previous mechanical issue since I hadn't seen any lights before either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and Welcome.  Sounds like you drained the battery (the brake lights were on the whole time).  Charge the battery or jump start the car and go from there.

Comment: @mike65535 - That sounds like an answer.

Comment: BTW - Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you drained the battery (the brake lights were probably on the whole time you had your foot on the pedal).

Charge the battery or jump start the car and go from there.